# What might be causing a need for alignment when you haven’t done something obvious?

Tags: alignment

I think my car needs an alignment however it had been parked up for some months prior to which I did an alignment and it was straight.

I know certain things can cause a need for alignment e.g. suspension work, hitting a curb, or pothole.  However let’s say it doesn’t seem any of these things have happened, what might have caused the car to go out of alignment?

Can driving on wrong pressure tyres etc cause it to go out of alignment?  Maybe some suspension items are wearing out?  I notice there is some play in the rear sway bar though it’s not a lot.  Could this be causing the car to go out of alignment in which case I must fix it before doing the alignment and would not doing so cause it to just go out of allignment again? Are there any factors other thN obvious one such as post suspension repairs, hitting a kerb or pothole that can cause a need for an alignment?

Comment: Without impact not much can go wrong. Bushings wear out, and fasteners not correctly tightened can go loose. Question:  Is steering wheel still centered when driving straight ahead?  Did you do quick test with string on both sides of car?  Can you see visible problem?

Comment: Car isn’t necessarily going left but it feels like it’s not pulling well and is going inwards.  I had this same experience before parking it up for many months and alugnmento did fix it.  It is taking turns very poorly though.  No I didn’t go the string test but I guess I’ll learn about that and diy alignment.

Comment: Are your wheel bearings okay?

Comment: @zipzit I don’t hear any sounds though I guess what I’m describing could be a symptom of a bearing issue.  Could a loose rear sway bar link cause it to keep misaligning?

Comment: Rear sta bar loose?  That should only affect the cars tilt during different conditions. No way would that affect alignment. Not the rear bar. Front stabar tie rod is possible, but not the rear. Again are steering wheel spokes centered when you are driving in a straight line ( less road crown issues)??

Comment: Assuming that you didn't hit anything with the car, ie potholes... And assuming that bolts were tighten properly... The only thing that can go wrong are deflated tyres or hardened due to sun radiation... And that could give you the feeling that the car can't steer properly... Even bushings don't fail by few months of inactivity... But what bothers me with my suggestion is that it is too obvious...