# Can you diy a four wheel alignment?

Tags: alignment

I notice there are diy guides on how to do a front end alignment.

Can the rear wheels also be done diy?

Will the car feel straight if you have a front end alignment but dont do the rear?  what are the consequences if not doing the rear?

Comment: All you measure at the front can be measured at the rear. The workshop manuals even give the relevant figures...

Comment: See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/69794/10976

Comment: And all you really need is a bar and a decent ruler applied with common sense...

Answer (score 1):

You can set toe on front and back and camber. But you can't measure or set thrust line or SAI angle. So all four wheels could be straight but not aligned to the thrust line of the vehicle and it would "dog track."

Comment: Measuring the chassis tends to show those - at least we found vehicles that were banana’d, rear axles that were further forward on one side to the other, one side shorter than the other. A plumb line and decent marking out on a flat floor...